# SQL Server Mirroring Removed

Tags: sql-server, mirroring

Does anyone know how to tell when SQL Server mirroring was removed from a database? My log file is flooded with login failures but I can't find mention of removing of a mirror.

Is there any DMV way of finding this out?

Comment: See if the mirror is in suspended state. In that case the mirror is broken, but not removed.

Comment: The databases are all In Recovery so looks like it as removed I believe

Comment: What is the version of SQL server you are running?

Comment: 2012 - I know but we had too

Comment: I have just started and stopped the end points and it looks to have sprung back into life.  My question now is what can cause the end point to mess up like this?

Comment: I think that it depends (my experience is limited). I think, we have such problems if there are issues with the network. I also have an issue with broken  mirror when I made a complex partition chaning procedure ([see my question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/105200/why-my-database-mirror-break-down-after-changing-file-group-settings-from-restri)).